# BGE pressing space bar while in play mode isn't running script

Tags: scripting, game-engine

I'm new to bge, reading a tutorial on matrix, I downloaded the linked file, a very simple task, I'm supposed to go to bge, press <kbd>P</kbd> then press <kbd>space</kbd> in order to run the script. the problem is, it's not, I googled it to search for other examples, I thought may be I'm doing something wrong, but everywhere it says that this his how you do it, can someone please enlighten me.
I'm attaching the .blend

[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is from pre 2.49. I'm pretty sure it runs into an error.

Always have the console window open when running the BGE with python code. Otherwise you will not see errors caused by Python code.

Convert the above sample to (BGE 2.5 and Python 3):

```
import bge 

controller = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
owner = controller.owner

rotation_matrix = [ [0,-1, 0],
                    [1, 0, 0],
                    [0, 0, 1]]

sensor = controller.sensors["space"]

if sensor.positive:
    owner.worldOrientation = rotation_matrix
```